# How to remove redirect virus in every browser?

Tags: browser, virus, redirection

I don't know if this is even a virus. Every time I open a non HTTPS website, it always redirecting me to an unwanted website.

I tried:

- Changing the DNS
- Scan using Adwcleaner
- Clear browsing data
- Reset the settings
- Blocking the site in host file
- Checking previously installed application

And nothing solve the problem.

Comment: Does it happen in other browsers? Are there unwanted extensions installed? Does the program shortcut has some strange url?

Comment: Yes, i tried it with mozilla and same thing happen. Anw, I found a solution =)

Answer (score 0):

I found this tutorial of VampireKingcoming in [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_gv9i-cj2SE)

1. Type 'regedit' in cmd
2. Go to HKEY_CURRENT_USER->Software->Microsoft->Internet Explorer->Main
3. Delete the 'Start Page'
4. Open browser(google chrome)
5. Go to settings then 'Reset Settings'

This fixed my problem.